# PyQt5 - QPixmap translate not effective

Tags: python, pyqt, qpixmap

I am working on an application where I a picture in a graphic scene.
I am able to scale and rotate the picture applying a QTransform, but the translate does not apply.

On the same picture I also draw some shapes (ellipses, rectangle...) which are following the transform, but the picture just does not move.

Code as below

In init part of the code

```
self.graph_scene = QGraphicsScene()
self.graph_view = QGraphicsView(self.graph_scene)
```

When loading the picture

```
transform = QTransform()
transform.scale(self.zoom_value / 100, self.zoom_value / 100)
transform.rotate(15)
transform.translate(50, 50)

# Loading picture
self.pixmap = QPixmap(picture_path)

# Add pixmap
self.graph_scene.addPixmap(self.pixmap) 

# Apply transform
self.graph_view.setTransform(transform)
```

I tried several solution, including applying transform directly to the pixmap itself, but looks as I miss something. Anyway I do, I can only scale and rotate, cannot translate only the picture.

Anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Translate relative to what? Unless you specify a scene rect (for the scene or the view), the view will always try to *center* the scene contents in the scroll area. Besides, you'll probably want to apply the transformations not on the view, nor the pixmap, but the pixmap item (the one returned by `addPixmap()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to musicamante comment, issue solved by applying the move to rectangle assigned to the scene rather than the pixmap.

Working perfectly.